# How to manage flask acounts to show different data to different users when they login?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

**I want when person login and goes to /MyEmployees to find his unique list with employees**

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
               id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
               name = db.Column(db.String(100))
               email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
               password = db.Column(db.String(100))
       
           def __init__(self, name, email, password):
               self.name = name
               self.email = email
               self.password = password
       
       
class Data(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(100))
   email = db.Column(db.String(100))
   phone = db.Column(db.String(100))

   def __init__(self, name, email, phone):
       self.name = name
       self.email = email
       self.phone = phone

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
   return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

Login method

```
#login method
@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form.get("email")
        password = request.form.get("password")

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email, password=password).first()

        if user:
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for("profile", usr=current_user.name))
        else:
            return f"<p>wrong password or email</p>"
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

Display the employees added

```
@app.route("/MyEmployees", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@login_required
def myemployees():
    all_data = Data.query.all()
    return render_template("myemployees.html", employees=all_data)
```

Here is the function of inserting new members in the list

```
@app.route('/insert', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def insert():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        phone = request.form['phone']

        my_data = Data(name, email, phone)
        db.session.add(my_data)
        db.session.commit()

        flash("Employee Inserted Successfully")

        return redirect(url_for("myemployees"))
```

The problem is that every user now has the same list of employees. I want to manage different acounts with different stored data in it, like company members.

Comment: Why not have a user category as an extra field in your user class and display different things based on the user category.

Comment: Is every new person going to have his own category? Isn't that bad if i have 100 users and 100 html files for each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `myemployees` mentioned. Does that mean that you have some users with a manager profile? if so, you should have a relationship within the user table which shows who's whose manager.  Use [self_referential](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/self_referential.html) to add a relationship. Then for each user, you can filter out only those users who have the manager as the current user.

Comment: I am new to programming and database but i will try this solution. Thanks!